# How to get JID for XMPP IOS framework

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat

I just downloaded XMPP framework for IOS and it has an example code when i run the example application it asks for **JID** and **Password**

Can anyone let me know how to implement real time chat in IOS.
And how to get JID?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A JID is an identifier to connect to an XMPP server. You can deploy your own server (like [ejabberd](https://www.ejabberd.im) for example), or you can create just an account on a public server (you can find one in this [directory](https://xmpp.net/directory.php) for example).